# GLSL Shader Error "Constructor calls may not have precision"

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl

*GLSL Shader Error
ERROR: 0:1: '(' : syntax error: Constructor calls may not have precision*

I'm seeing this error with Xcode 6 on an iOS 8 app based on GLPaint demo... (works fine in iOS7)

I also noticed they no longer use the "STRINGIFY" thing in version 1.13 of GLPaint demo.

---

.vsh

```
static const char* BaseVS = STRINGIFY
(


attribute highp vec4 inVertex;

uniform highp mat4 MVP;
uniform highp float pointSize;
uniform highp vec4 vertexColor;
uniform highp float brushRotation;

varying highp vec4 color;


void main()
{
    gl_Position = MVP * inVertex;
    gl_PointSize = pointSize;
    color = vertexColor;
}

);
```

---

.fsh

```
static const char* BaseFS = STRINGIFY
(


uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform sampler2D normalMap;
uniform highp float brushRotation;

varying highp vec4 color;
varying highp vec3 normal;
varying highp vec3 lightDir;
varying highp vec3 eyeVec;

precision highp float;

 void main (void)

{


highp float vRotation = (brushRotation/180.0)*3.14;;
highp float mid = 0.5;
highp vec2 rotated = vec2(cos(vRotation) * (gl_PointCoord.x - mid) + sin(vRotation) * (gl_PointCoord.y - mid) + mid,
                    cos(vRotation) * (gl_PointCoord.y - mid) - sin(vRotation) * (gl_PointCoord.x - mid) + mid);
highp vec4 rotatedTexture = texture2D( texture,  rotated);


gl_FragColor = color * rotatedTexture;

}

);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in a method used for random generation. I removed the "high" before the vec2() construction. (Sigh)

```
 highp float rand(highp vec2 co)
{
    return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,highp vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}
```

Comment: Damn! You must have gotten "high" to get this. Just kidding :) . You are a Saviour. Thanks a ton.